# AS3: Get the average out of an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, multidimensional-array, actionscript

I'm making an application that will calculate the average grades for students.
They have input textfields for each of the subjects they take, where they can insert the grades (going from 1 to 6, where 6 is the best grade).
Been trying to get the average score out of the array, but I just can't get it right. It's not calculating the average that is the problem, it's accessing the numeric values that people insert. As of now I can't return any of the numbers that people type.

Here is the code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.controls.DataGrid; 
import fl.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn; 
import fl.events.DataGridEvent; 
import fl.data.DataProvider; 
import fl.controls.ScrollPolicy;

knapp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, klikk);

function klikk (evt:MouseEvent) {
    //Array for å samle alle verdiene
    var karakterer = 0;
    var karakterOversikt:Array = new Array();

    karakterOversikt = [
        {Fag: "Engelsk", "Karakter": uint(inputEng.text)},
        {Fag: "Geografi", "Karakter": uint(inputGeo.text)},
        {Fag: "Historie Vg3", "Karakter": uint(inputHist.text)},
        {Fag: "Kroppsøving Vg3", "Karakter": uint(inputGym.text)},
        {Fag: "Naturfag", "Karakter": uint(inputNat.text)},
        {Fag: "Matematikk Vg1", "Karakter": uint(inputMatVg1.text)},
        {Fag: "Matematik Vg2", "Karakter": uint(inputMatVg2.text)},
        {Fag: "Norsk Hovedmål, skriftlig", "Karakter": uint(inputNorH.text)},
        {Fag: "Norsk Sidemål, skriftlig", "Karakter": uint(inputNorS.text)},
        {Fag: "Norsk Muntlig", "Karakter": uint(inputNorM.text)},
        {Fag: "Religion og etikk", "Karakter": uint(inputRel.text)},
        {Fag: "Samfunnsfag", "Karakter": uint(inputSamf.text)},
        {Fag: "Programfag 1", "Karakter": uint(inputProg1.text)},
        {Fag: "Programfag 2", "Karakter": uint(inputProg2.text)},
        {Fag: "Programfag 3", "Karakter": uint(inputProg3.text)},
        {Fag: "Programfag 4", "Karakter": uint(inputProg4.text)},
        {Fag: "Programfag 5", "Karakter": uint(inputProg5.text)},
        {Fag: "Programfag 6", "Karakter": uint(inputProg6.text)},
        {Fag: "Eksamen 1", "Karakter": uint(inputEksamen1.text)},
        {Fag: "Eksamen 2", "Karakter": uint(inputEksamen2.text)},
        {Fag: "Eksamen 3", "Karakter": uint(inputEksamen3.text)},
        {Fag: "Eksamen 4", "Karakter": uint(inputEksamen4.text)},
        {Fag: "Eksamen 5", "Karakter": uint(inputEksamen5.text)},
    ];

    //sorterer karakterene etter høyeste
    karakterOversikt.sortOn("Karakter", Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC); 

    //Lager datagrid med alle karakterene
    fagOversiktGrid.dataProvider = new DataProvider(karakterOversikt);
    fagOversiktGrid.columns = ["Fag", "Karakter"];
    fagOversiktGrid.columns[0].width = 190;
    fagOversiktGrid.columns[1].width = 70;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the average is simply the sum of all `Karakter` values divided by `karakterOversikt.length`:

```
function averageScore(karakterOversikt:Array):Number {
    var sum:Number = 0;
    for each (var item:Object in karakterOversikt) {
        sum += item.Karakter;
    }
    return sum / karakterOversikt.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm not getting any values out of sum. Tried to move the var sum:Number = 0; outside of the function, aswell as insert sum / karakterOversikt.length into another var then return that var. But when I try to trace sum outside of the function it's giving me errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: You would use this function from somewhere like `var average:Number = averageScore(karakterOversikt)`. What errors is it giving you?

Comment: I realised that I need to change my arrays around. First have one array that had all the info, then make a loop that inserted all the info into a new array that would be the database for the datagrid. That leaves me with greater flexibility as I now have two arrays that can be used for different stuff. And when doing that I got your function to work with the first array.
Thank you for helping out! :)